# The Views both inherits Inavigationaware. But why ViewC just exec the OnNavigatedFrom function, ViewA can execute three functions in turn?

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm trying to use [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism) and [HandyControl](https://github.com/HandyOrg/HandyControl) to create a project, **but now I have a very strange problem.**

This is My Github repo:  https://github.com/sanshiliuxiao/PrismRegionWithHcTabControl

(If you know Chinese, you can see the principle of my implementation) My Blog: http://sanshiliuxiao.top/notebook/CSharp/20210611-PrismWithTabControl/

I have three views (A, B, Cwithparameters) whose ViewModel inherits Inavigationaware.

If I click  the button (`ViewA` or `ViewB`), It can execute three functions in turn (`OnNavigatedFrom`、`IsNavigationTarget`、`OnNavigatedTo`).

But, if I click the button (`ViewC`), it just execute the `OnNavigatedFrom`.

Why? It's so strange!!!

This gif image.

Click ViewA gif:
[image: Click ViewA gif]

Click ViewC gif:
[image: Click ViewC gif]

[Test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuett.png)
[image: Click ViewC gif]

Comment: After testing, it is found that when two view of the same type (but different ViewName, such as `ViewC` `View-aaa`) appear, the `View-aaa` only triggered  `OnNavigatedFrom` ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhhh!!! I know why there is such a bug.

I Have two views， one is ViewC(  `ViewName = ViewC`, the url source is `ViewC`), one is ViewC(But `ViewName =View-aaa`, the url source is `View-aaa`).

The key is here： `Prism.Wpf.RegionNavigationContentLoader.cs`

```cs
     private IEnumerable<object> GetCandidatesFromRegionViews(IRegion region, string candidateNavigationContract)
        {
            return region.Views.Where(v => ViewIsMatch(v.GetType(), candidateNavigationContract));
        }

        private static bool ViewIsMatch(Type viewType, string navigationSegment)
        {
            var names = new[] { viewType.Name, viewType.FullName };
            return names.Any(x => x.Equals(navigationSegment, StringComparison.Ordinal));
        }
```

the `navigationSegment` is `View-ccc`,  So, Can't to match.